# State root mismatch error at mining genesis block

Tags: mining, private-blockchain, genesis, besu

I am working on a private Besu implementation. I made some modifications to the open source package, and when I went to start a new chain instance it gives a state root mismatch error for the genesis block.

I can start a non-mining boot node without issues. However, when I start a mining node, it gives state root mismatch and illegal block RLP errors when trying to mine block 1. It can't even mine the genesis block, and I'm at a loss for what could be causing this. The genesis files are the same. The only change I made in the Java was to make the block reward zero, and I'm not sure why that would affect the generation of the block or how it would impact the root hash.

It is able to connect and sync with the boot node. It starts up, syncs with the boot node, and then when it tries to mine block one it blows up. The two nodes are on separate machines, but on the same internal network.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Errors:

`Invalid block: state root mismatch (expected=0x3e6870f457dca4a0cd037a2967822916e568b173cc0490d025935020d11ed2d3, actual=0x81b0b7888360c0b63969f5a8e0c680007979dbfd8662c4dca64b7203c4a70288)`

`Invalid block RLP : 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`

EDIT: I have verified what is causing the issue is setting the block reward to zero, but I don't understand why that's an issue. The function itself returns a boolean, and the value is used as a calculation inside the function, but not returned outside the function. Further, the error isn't being thrown by the function but by the BlockMiner, so I'm really confused where to start looking for the actual problem. Java is not my forte, so any assistance is appreciated.

function:

```
  protected boolean rewardCoinbase(
      final MutableWorldState worldState,
      final BlockHeader header,
      final List<BlockHeader> ommers,
      final boolean skipZeroBlockRewards) {

      blockReward = Wei.ZERO;
      
      if (skipZeroBlockRewards && blockReward.isZero()) {
          return true;
      }
     
      final Wei coinbaseReward = getCoinbaseReward(blockReward, header.getNumber(), ommers.size());
      final WorldUpdater updater = worldState.updater();
      final Address miningBeneficiary = getMiningBeneficiaryCalculator().calculateBeneficiary(header);
      final MutableAccount miningBeneficiaryAccount = updater.getOrCreate(miningBeneficiary).getMutable();
      
      miningBeneficiaryAccount.incrementBalance(coinbaseReward);
      
      for (final BlockHeader ommerHeader : ommers) {
          if (ommerHeader.getNumber() - header.getNumber() > MAX_GENERATION) {
              LOG.info(
                      "Block processing error: ommer block number {} more than {} generations. Block {}",
                      ommerHeader.getNumber(),
                      MAX_GENERATION,
                      header.getHash().toHexString()
              );
        
              return false;
          }

          final MutableAccount ommerCoinbase = updater.getOrCreate(ommerHeader.getCoinbase()).getMutable();
          final Wei ommerReward = getOmmerReward(blockReward, header.getNumber(), ommerHeader.getNumber());
      
          ommerCoinbase.incrementBalance(ommerReward);
      }

      updater.commit();
      
      return true;
  }
```

Comment: Hmmm I cannot test it, but just a wild guess : You seem to be  bypassing the coinbase tx commitment to the state with ` if (skipZeroBlockRewards && blockReward.isZero())`  this commit may add a new account to the global state. I am not sure why this if statement is necessary to be honest ?

Comment: I originally thought the same thing, so I tried it with a zero balance both with and without the bypass, and both times resulted in the same error. Only when using a positive value for blockReward does it work. The weirder thing is that the error isn't generated by the class this function is in, but changing the value of blockReward in this function is what causes the error. The function returns a boolean, so I don't understand why an internal variable value change that doesn't get returned causes errors in another class, but they are definitely caused by that var value.